# How to get user first_name in telegram chatbot build with dialogflow_es

Tags: dialogflow-es, telegram, payload

I'm new to Dialogflow and want to understand how to extract a user's first_name in a Telegram chatbot I created. I built a chatbot using intents + inline editor (code below) and learned how to get users' data from responses using agent.parameters, but still can't code anything to extract parts of user's payload data to get first_name without asking for it. I used the following code but it didn't work:

`let display_name = agent.originalRequest.payload.data.message.from.first_name`

Would be super grateful if someone can explain the right code function to extract this data!

My full inline code is below.

```js
'use strict';
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const admin = require ('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
admin.auth();
const db = admin.firestore();

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
  
  function welcome(agent) {
   agent.add(`Hi! Do you want to create an account?`);
  }
  
  function createUser(agent) {
     agent.add(`Thank you! You have successfully created your account`);
     let uid = makeid(28);
     let email = agent.parameters.email;
     let password = agent.parameters.user_password;
     let display_name = agent.parameters.display_name;
     admin.auth().createUser({uid: uid, email: email, password: password});
     db.collection('users').doc(uid).set(
       {uid: uid, 
        display_name: display_name, 
        });
  }
 
  function fallback(agent) {
    agent.add(`I didn't understand`);
    agent.add(`I'm sorry, can you try again?`);
  }
 
  let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set('Welcome Intent', welcome);
  intentMap.set('account.creation', createUser);
  intentMap.set('Default Fallback Intent', fallback);
  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that worked for me

```js
 let payload = agent.originalRequest;
 let firstname = payload.payload.data.from.first_name;
```